# Can EDI files have ~ in data?

Tags: edi

I'm parsing a EDI file and splitting by ~s.  I am wondering if it's possible for EDI to have ~ in the data itself?  Is there a rule that says no ~ in the data?  This is for 810/850 etc

Comment: No. If the envelope specifies `~` as the segment separator, then that character is used to separate segments and can't exist in the data itself. If that character can appear in the data, then the envelope should specify a different segment separator.

Comment: ok once you get a thumbs up I will be for sure that your answer is right.

Comment: The ISA is always 106 in length.  The 106th character is the segment terminator.  Different partners can use different characters as their segment terminator.  That's the appropriate way to determine how to parse segments on inbound transactions.

Answer (score 25):

The value defined in the 106th character of the ISA segment (or, alternatively – to be a bit less brittle to whitespace issues – the 1st character *after* the `ISA16` element) is the segment delimiter (in official terms: the `segment terminator`). Most of the time people specify the `~` character, but other choices are certainly valid.

In this example, the 106th character is `~`:

`ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*AMAZONDS       *01*TESTID         *070808*1310*U*00401*000000043*1*T*+~`

Instead of counting 106 characters (which, again, can be brittle to whitespace issues), you can count 16 *elements* – that is, 16 asterisks – to find the value for `ISA16` (which is `+`), and then pick the next character (which is `~`).

There are two relevant sections in the official X12 specification (bolded for emphasis):

> 12.5.4.3 Delimiter Specifications
>
> The delimiters consist of three separators and a terminator. The
> delimiters are devised for inclusion within the data stream of the transfer. The delimiters are:
>
> - **segment terminator** [note: this is the one we're discussing]
> - data element separator
> - component element separator
> - repetition separator
>
> The delimiters are assigned by the interchange sender. These characters are disjoint from those of the data elements; **if a character is selected** for the data element separator, the component element separator, the repetition separator or the segment terminator from those available for the data elements, **that character is no longer available during this interchange for use in a data element**. The instance of the terminator (`<tr>`) must be different from the instance of the data element separator (`<gs>`), the component element separator (`<us>`) and the repetition separator (`<rs>`). The data element separator, component element separator and repetition separator must not have the same character assignment.

So, according to this part of the spec, if the `~` is used as the segment terminator, then the use of the `~` is disallowed in a data element (that is, the textual body).

Now, let's look at section 12.5.A.5 – Recommendations for the Delimiters:

> Delimiter characters must be chosen with care, after consideration of data content, limitations of the transmission protocol(s) used, and applicable industry conventions. In the absence of other guidelines, the following recommendations are offered:

> `<tr> terminator`: `~` | **Note:** the "~" was chosen for its infrequency of use in textual data.

This section is saying that `~` was chosen as the default because `~` is seldom found in textual data (it would have been a bad idea, for example, to use `.` as the default, since that's such a common inclusion).

That said, even though using the segment terminator is technically prohibited, it's still *possible* for an EDI transmission to inadvertently include `~` in the textual data – in other words, your trading partner may include this by accident. Further, the `BIN` and `BSD` (binary data) segments can certainly include `~` (though these may not apply based on the transaction sets you're working with).

In [our parsing API](https://www.stedi.com/docs/edi-core), we apply a set of specific set of patterns based on the type of segment we encounter. For us, it's not sufficient to split naively based on the segment delimiter alone because we may encounter binary segments (`BIN`, `BSD`), where it's possible that the segment delimiter character is included in the textual data.

For a regular segment (i.e. not `BIN` or `BSD`), the logic is something like this:

- Consume the segment code (i.e. the characters before the first element delimiter).
- Consume each element of the segment based on the element delimiter.
- Stop if the next character is a segment delimiter or a new line.

As an example, for segment `BEG*PO-00001**20210901~`, the process would look like:

- Consume `BEG`. Since this is not a special segment (`BIN` or `BSD`), consume elements by splitting on `*`.
- Consume `PO-00001`.
- Consume `''`.
- Consume `20210901`.
- Stop since next char is `~`.

(The pattern for binary segments is different from the pattern we use for regular segments.)

- [Here's an example](https://www.stedi.com/edi/inspector?value=JIZQggVADFEAQMU6slrhAWpiYCyYmA8gHIAiI6GUAjBACoCiI9wZVC0A7FABx8QaAZhqwAqigAstFDDmShghhADUAPwBQAcRAQACkVz0AYhVwFi5XQCYYPAJw06tmfYCsEABpTaUTSwheN1gYUU0AIUYtFAgzegBTAGd6OSD7ADYICBcefl5NAGExACUIcPoIMRAyTWLGYwgiAEUvWvqIAJpNEnssHFpNPBBo%2BgALAEtEuESJgAcAW3iAOwAXOABjAHt52YAbeJWkuABPTYBXACc4TYuAE3iLgDpu3uxodMHhiGMbuHuVgCG432tzg4yWADMbvMAStxpslnAAQAjc5rU6Xa53B6JAA0cD28QBiXicAAbpNxmsAJrnK5gdZbM6rZ60s4bAGIgG7RKbAkXcFrcFkzbjdZJfHrUacgDmpIxV3iAFoYcCkbdbhcklNOaDZgDjotVtMDnCljK8UjdocrgqNtt5syxbD4YjZlqIQ9luLLbq4I6pf6bsrrJI4KM6Tq-galbDwysVrMAFwAehTAHdM48ATCAF4Ix5beYphWxxnnFkvPrcT7RABqlLWowTybTmfT2bzBaLKa1K0uSymKz5fYHSKWxzBh3mSvB612Z1u4JlcBl4whK0Ss8RzM2s2W8VBvxu4zXS259qWS7hCLg6apE0RQig0eOUyhVwBcAhZ12uzgHrMrcAAUmwrKMDwAUkKwCusN6Dkisx7McACUjxwHo%2BzEqS0pkvKdJYvcVxsFBAK3Mc6FjJyADW76-DMe6zMuSJrGAXZLIW2z4n6hLYfaixIjKQJLAAhN0dDlLg7GcfMjzUcctzrLiwBLOsjwQPY1gQAA0tSZAFOJHQNAA6gAEiAjAaVpZkWYZAQFNKFy7OMpJkOC1Hgok3RaWQAJOV%2BblLB5g7dIoTjWG4YZ4MJcAgCsHRnFSpLhd0kgdESCb7BAxmQPYvCiGlVQQAUBSVEsSWgnFsJJJo9BkB4VmVHoIAAPpaMULV1LoWTVl1hkADLGVJyKQeEALUQ8oWCNYQhwGAV44reYB4UsZzxKl6WwisWU5Rp%2BVQIoVSaHojClG8PVMNkUDpEqbh3UqNDWI9x1EHQdCKIwkA0LwjxQGlJAVCA2mCOkNBcD1WThP1ShvGxAL5hxRaFPQehZHoJSCPYjz2PYtbZeM9xwPQFwAusE30nB4wUisk7Gdy5Mvc42QQJ9ECRY8khaQDHTA5ImngxDUMwzgcMIzJyOo-oGNuFjON42Q8QLgAHqSBSbLmk5q0seEXHCyL7IzEBhSzkBPdjEDc0DIO8FpgvQ3QsPSUjGgFCjaMYxF2O4xoQzRG5iRbDrIAVrcUzGTctERrMyMVJkCj%2BJZQiKKEfjaJZdDxxowCs3Qch55nQA) of how our parser "fails" on a `~` in the textual data when the `ISA16` segment delimiter is also `~`; the [JSON representation](https://www.stedi.com/edi/inspector?value=JIZQggVADFEAQMU6slrhAWpiYCyYmA8gHIAiI6GUAjBACoCiI9wZVC0A7FABx8QaAZhqwAqigAstFDDmShghhADUAPwBQAcRAQACkVz0AYhVwFi5XQCYYPAJw06tmfYCsEABpTaUTSwheN1gYUU0AIUYtFAgzegBTAGd6OSD7ADYICBcefl5NAGExACUIcPoIMRAyTWLGYwgiAEUvWvqIAJpNEnssHFpNPBBo%2BgALAEtEuESJgAcAW3iAOwAXOABjAHt52YAbeJWkuABPTYBXACc4TYuAE3iLgDpu3uxodMHhiGMbuHuVgCG432tzg4yWADMbvMAStxpslnAAQAjc5rU6Xa53B6JAA0cD28QBiXicAAbpNxmsAJrnK5gdZbM6rZ60s4bAGIgG7RKbAkXcFrcFkzbjdZJfHrUacgDmpIxV3iAFoYcCkbdbhcklNOaDZgDjotVtMDnCljK8UjdocrgqNtt5syxbD4YjZlqIQ9luLLbq4I6pf6bsrrJI4KM6Tq-galbDwysVrMAFwAehTAHdM48ATCAF4Ix5beYphWxxnnFkvPrcT7RABqlLWowTybTmfT2bzBaLKa1K0uSymKz5fYHSKWxzBh3mSvB612Z1u4JlcBl4whK0Ss8RzM2s2W8VBvxu4zXS259qWS7hCLg6apE0RQig0eOUyhVwBcAhZ12uzgHrMrcAAUmwrKMDwAUkKwCusN6Dkisx7McACUjxwHo%2BzEqS0pkvKdJYvcVxsFBAK3Mc6FjJyADW76-DMe6zMuSJrGAXZLIW2z4n6hLYfaixIjKQJLAAhN0dDlLg7GcfMjzUcctzrLiwBLOsjwQPY1gQAA0tSZAFOJHQNAA6gAEiAjAaVpZkWYZAQFNKFy7OMpJkOC1Hgok3RaWQAJOV%2BblLB5g7dIoTjWG4YZ4MJcAgCsHRnFSpLhd0kgdESCb7BAxmQPYvCiGlVQQAUBSVEsSWgnFsJJJo9BkB4VmVHoIAAPpaMULV1LoWTVl1hkADLGVJyKQeEALUQ8oWCNYQhwGAV44reYB4UsZzxKl6WwisWU5Rp%2BVQIoVSaHojClG8PVMNkUDpEqbh3UqNDWI9x1EHQdCKIwkA0LwjxQGlJAVCA2mCOkNBcD1WThP1ShvGxAL5hxRaFPQehZHoJSCPYjz2PYtbZeM9xwPQFwAusE30nB4wUisk7Gdy5Mvc42QQJ9ECRY8khaQDHTA5ImngxDUMwzgcMIzJyOo-oGNuFjON42Q8QLgAHqSBSbLmk5q0seEXHCyL7IzEBhSzkBPdjEDc0DIO8FpgvQ3QsPSUjGgFCjaMYxF2O4xoQzRG5iRbDrIAVrcUzGTctERrMyMVJkCj%2BJZQiKKEfjaJZdDxxowCs3Qch55nQA&view=json) is particularly helpful for seeing the issue.
- [Here's an example](https://www.stedi.com/edi/inspector?value=JIZQggVADFEAQMU6slrhAWpiYCyYmA8gHIAiI6GUAjBACoCiI9wZVC0A7FABx8QaAZhqwAqigAstFDDmShghhADUAPQBQAcRAQACkVz0AYhVwFi5XQCYYPAJw06tmfYCsEABpTaUTSwheN1gYUU0AIUYtFAgzegBTAGd6OSD7ADYICBcefl5NAGExACUIcPoIMRAyTWLGYwgiAEUvWvqIAJpNEnssHFpNPBBo%2BgALAEtEuESJgAcAW3iAOwAXOABjAHt52YAbeJWkuABPTYBXACc4TYuAE3iLgDpu3uxodMHhiGMbuHuVgCG432tzg4yWADMbvMAStxpslnAAQAjc5rU6Xa53B6JAA0cD28QBiXicAAbpNxmsAJrnK5gdZbM6rR5wAB%2BtLOGwBiIBu0SmwJF3Ba3BZM243WSXx61GPIA5qSMVd4gBaGHApG3W4XJJTHmg2YA46LVbTA5wpbyvFI3aHK7KjbbebMyWw%2BGI2a6iEPZZSm0GuAu2VBm5q6ySOCjOn6v7G1WwqMrFazABcAHp0wB3HOPAEwgBeCMeW3m6eVCcZ5xZLz63E%2B0QAapS1qNk2nMzms3nC8XS%2BndStLkspitBYPh0ilscwYd5qrwetdmdbuD5XB5eMIStEgvEczNrNlvFQb8buNN0s%2BU6lqu4Qi4FmqRNEUIoHHjlMoVcAXAIWddl2OBvWZW4AApNhWUYHmApIVmFdZ7xHJFZj2Y4AEpWT0fZiVJOUySVOksXuK42FggFbmOVkxh5ABrL9fhmQ9ZjXJE1jAXslhLbZ8UDQlcKdRYkXlIElgAQm6OhylwTjuPmR5aOOW51lxYAlnWR4IHsawIAAaWpMgCkkjoGgAdQACRARgtJ0iyrOMgICjlC5dnGUkyHBWjwUSbodLIAEXN-Dyli8kdukUJxrDcSM8FEuAQBWDozipUlIu6SQOiJZN9ggUzIHsXhRAyqoIAKApKiWFLQQS2Ekk0egyA8GzKj0EAAH0tGKNq6l0LI6x64yABlTJk5EYPCAFaIecLBGsIQ4DAW8cQfMACKWM54nSzLYRWHK8q0wqoEUKpND0RhSjePqmGyKB0lVNwHtVGhrGe06iDoOhFEYSAaF4R4oAykgKhAXTBHSGguD6rJwkGpQ3g4gEiy40tCnoPQsj0EpBHsR57HsBtcvGe44HoC4AXWKb6UQ8YKRWGdTL5Sm3ucbIIG%2BiBoseSQdKBjpQckbTIahmG4ZwBGkbk1H0f0LG3BxvGCbIeJlwAD1JApNgLGcNaWAiLjhZF9mZiAIrZyAXtxiBeZBsHeB04XYboeHZJRjQCjRjGsai3H8Y0IZog8xItj1kBq1uKZTJuejo1mVGKkyBR-GsoRFFCPxtGsuhE40YB2boOQC%2BzoA) of our parser succeeding on a `~` in the textual data when the `ISA16` segment delimiter is `^`.
- Lastly, [here's an example](https://www.stedi.com/edi/inspector?value=JIZQggVADFEAQMU6slrhAWpiYCyYmA8gHIAiI6GUAjBACoCiI9wZVC0A7FABx8QaAZhqwAqigAstFDDmShghhADUAKADiICAAUiuegDEKuAsXLaATDB4BOGnWszbAVggANKbShqWEXi6wMKJqAEKMGigQJvQApgDO9HIBtgBsEBBOPPy8agDCYgBKEKH0EGIgZGqFjIYQRACKHtW1EH40aiS2WDi0anggkfQAFgCW8XDxYwAOALaxAHYALnAAxgD2s9MANrFLCXAAnusArgBOcOtnACaxZwB0nd3Y0Kn9gxCGV3C3SwCGo121zgowWADMrrM-ktRusFnA-gAjU4rY7nS43O7xAA0cB2sT%2B8VicAAbuNRisAJqnC5gVYbE7Le5waknNZ-eF-bbxdZ4s6glagknrUarBK41bDDkAc2JaIusQAtFDAQjrtczgkJhzgdM-od5stJnsYQtpTiEdt9hd5WtNrNGaLobD4dNNWC7osxRadXAHZK-VclZZJHBhjTtT99YroWGlktpgAuAD0yYA7hn7n8oQAvOH3DazZPymP005Mp49bjvSIANXJK2G8aTqYzaazufzheTmqW5wWEyWvN7-YRC0OIP2s0VoNW2xO11B0rg0tGYKW8Rn8MZ62mi1iwO%2BV1Gq4WXLtC0XMLhcDTFLG8KEUCjhwmEIufzgYJO222cHdjLXAAFOsSzDHc-4JEs-KrNeA4ItMOyHAAlMyOi7ISxJSiSco0hitwXGwkF-NchzMiMHIANZvt8Uy7tMS4IisYCdgsBabLivr4phdrzAi0oAgsACEnR0KUuCsexsz3JRhzXKs2LAAsqz3BAtiWBAADSlJkHkoltHUADqAASICMGpGkmWZ%2Bl%2BHkUpnNsozEmQoKUaC8SdBpZB-A5n4uQsbkDp0igOJYLihngglwCASxtCcFLEqFnSSG0BLxrsECGZAti8KIKUVBAeR5OUCwJcCMXQgkaj0GQbgWeUOggAA%2BhohRNTU2gZFWHX6QAMoZEmIhBoR-JRdzBYIlhCHAYCXliN5gDhCwnLEyWpdCSwZVlam5VAigVGoOiMMULxdUwmRQKkiouDdio0JY92HUQdB0IojCQDQvD3FAKUkGUICaYIqQ0FwXUZKEvVKC8LF-HmbGFvk9A6BkOhFIItj3LYtg1ploy3HA9BnH8qxjbSsGjGSSwToZXKk09jiZBA70QOF9ySBpf1tIDkjqaDYMQ1DOAw3DUmI8juhoy4GNYzjZCxPOAAexJ5OsOYTirCw4WcMKIrs9MQCFTOQA9mMQJzANA7wGn85DdDQ5JCN5EjKNo2FmPYwMkQufEGxayA5bXBMhlXNR4bTIjZTpAovjmUIijBD4GjmXQ0fAMzdByJn0dAA&view=json) of our parsing succeeding where the `~` is specified in `ISA16`, but has been omitted altogether in favor of newlines – which we see occasionally.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see you have an EDI service I was debating on getting a paid API mostly for checking if the EDI files are any good before parsing but that's basically the only thing I need...

Comment: The API has a free tier of 1k req/mo (no credit card required); it likely wouldn't cost you anything to use it unless you're at a high volume. https://www.stedi.com/products/pricing

Comment: Yes but I went with inhouse solution because if the service goes offline its gg.